# Fortifying move to complete a Risk mission

Tags: risk

When playing the North American 1993 version of secret mission Risk, can a mission be acomplished with a fortifying move?

Example:If your mission is, “Conquer 18 TERRITORIES with at least 2 SOLDIERS on each”, can you end your turn already occupying 17 territories with at least 2 soldiers on each & 1 territory with just 1 soldier on it & fortify that last territory requiring the second soldier thus, now that 18 territories have at least 2 soldiers on them, reveal your mission & win the game?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  You can even win during your opponents turn when they complete your missions for you.

Do you control 18 territories?  Do they have at least 2 armies on them?  If yes to both, you win.

Comment: Yes indeed what was I thinking.